# Equal (==) and equal (===) not working for me

Tags: jquery, hash, equals-operator

I am using if condition in jquery and == is not working for me nor === . :(
Here is my code:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var hash = hash.replace('#', ' ');
  alert(hash); /* Returns abc.*/
if( hash === 'abc'){
            alert(hash); /* not coming here.*/
        $('.tab').removeClass('is-active');
    }
```

Any help? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'#abc'` not `'abc'`.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: What do you really see when you get the first `alert(hash)`

Comment: I think you forgot the `#` character. You should use `hash === '#abc'` instead

Comment: I replaced the # with empty space before doing this.

Comment: i see abc on alert.

Comment: What does the URL look like you are trying this command on?

Comment: `var hash = hash.replace('#', ' ');` here you are replacing `#` with `WHITE SPACE` instead of `EMPTY` string. Use `var hash = hash.replace('#', '');` this instead

Comment: http://localhost/creative/wp-admin/admin.php?page=new_page&name=abc#abc

Comment: @GHOST93 how i can replace wth EMPTY string ?

Comment: Take the second line code this `var hash = hash.replace('#', '');`

Comment: Take a look at @Anil's answer

Comment: Wow @GHOST93 thanks alot man :) 
Fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`window.location.hash` will return `#abc` not `abc`. So, Replace below code::

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

With this::

```
var hash = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];
```

FULL code will be::

```
var hash = window.location.hash.split('#')[1];
if( hash === 'abc'){
    $('.tab').removeClass('is-active');
}
```

It will work.

Comment: @DanishMalik If it helped you, please upvote the answer and accept it to helping others.

Comment: Yeah i did but they were not letting me to do it before 40 seconds. Thanks again :) all of you.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.hash` will return `#abc` not `abc`. You're also removing the # but replacing it with `' '`, not `''`. Try doing your comparison like this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
alert(hash); /* Returns abc.*/
if( hash === '#abc'){
        alert(hash); /* not coming here.*/
    $('.tab').removeClass('is-active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You replace the # with a ' ' (space) .. and hence what you really have in hash is a " abc" and not "abc" ... try the below instead

```js
window.location.hash = "abc";
var hash = window.location.hash;
var hash = hash.replace('#', '');
  alert(hash); /* Returns abc.*/
if( hash === 'abc'){
            alert(hash); /* now comes here*/
        //$('.tab').removeClass('is-active');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with '' and not with a space ' ', its working.

```js
var hash = '#abc';
var hash = hash.replace('#', '');
  alert(hash); /* Returns abc.*/
if( hash === 'abc'){
            alert(hash); /* not coming here.*/

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the current URL is http://www.example.com/yourfile.htm#abc

```
var hash = window.location.hash;    // hash = #abc
if( hash === '#abc'){
    //You are in now
    $('.tab').removeClass('is-active');
}
```

Hope this will helps.